# Where can I find List of known program addresses in Solana Mainnet

Tags: solana-program

- I want to display program addresses that are invoked in a transaction, but in a more understandable way. What is the best way to format the raw address I have into something meaningful?
- I remember seeing a JSON with a list of known programs, but I cannot recall where.
- Could someone point me to the right resource here?

**Added Explorer Image for Understanding my intention**

[image]

Comment: In reference to [@nick-garfield](https://solana.stackexchange.com/users/287/nick-garfield)'s answer, please note that the Explorer has been relocated to a new repository. Therefore, here is the updated link to access it: [Known programs Solana Explorer](https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/17f644efa1f6f174e1dd7bc46bc397ca55f0a004/app/utils/tx.ts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [list of programs named in the Solana Explorer can be found in the source code](https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/master/app/utils/programs.ts):

```
export const PROGRAM_INFO_BY_ID: { [address: string]: ProgramInfo } = {
    '11111111111111111111111111111111': {
        deployments: ALL_CLUSTERS,
        name: PROGRAM_NAMES.SYSTEM,
    },
    '22Y43yTVxuUkoRKdm9thyRhQ3SdgQS7c7kB6UNCiaczD': {
        deployments: [Cluster.MainnetBeta],
        name: PROGRAM_NAMES.SERUM_SWAP,
    },
    '27haf8L6oxUeXrHrgEgsexjSY5hbVUWEmvv9Nyxg8vQv': {
        deployments: [Cluster.MainnetBeta],
        name: PROGRAM_NAMES.RAYDIUM_LP_2,
    },
    '2rHhojZ7hpu1zA91nvZmT8TqWWvMcKmmNBCr2mKTtMq4': {
        deployments: [Cluster.Devnet],
        name: PROGRAM_NAMES.WORMHOLE_NFT,
    },
...(huge list of names continues)...
```

Many open-source programs were published to the Anchor program registry (https://apr.dev) however as of Mar 2024 this no seems to exist.

Comment: Looks like apr.dev doesn't work anymore. :(